# Choosing Cosmos Partition Keys

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb, database-partitioning

I'm creating a proof of concept for a micro service that will query a Cosmos DB. This DB will contain significant amounts of data culled from thousands of SQL databases. Each SQL database is a site with a `siteId` and each record has a `uniqueref` (that is unique *within that site* but not globally). The idea of the Cosmos DB is to hold documents which contain all the bits of data that a very broad search function can query (I think there are something like 25+ possible search terms). However, about 82% of all searches are by the `uniqueref` alone (the user does not need to choose the `siteId` as they will already be logged into their own site effectively and cannot search any others). This, along with a further 7 combinations of terms, covers around 97.5% of all searches.

The reason we're looking at Cosmos is because the SQL databases are large and their structure is rather less than optimal, meaning these searches load 10's or even 100's of thousands of rows of data from multiple tables in order to join them in memory (no enforced foreign keys is on of the sub optimal design decisions) to return perhaps just one row of data. We cannot alter the SQL databases unfortunately.

What I'm trying to decide is what would make a good partition key in Cosmos? The `uniqueref` is not guaranteed to be globally unique at all meaning it alone is no good if I've understood the documents correctly, as you would have tens of thousands of logical partitions which may have anything from 1 to maybe 3000 records in it.

The amount of data per site is hugely variable: Some may have a relative handful of records, perhaps a couple of thousand or less, and some may have 100's of thousands so `siteId` feels like a physical partition hotspot waiting to happen, as if we have 3000 sites then that's 3000 logical partitions, I think, with very variable amounts of data in them, unless I've misunderstood how hotspots occur

The other possibility is to synthesise a key from, say, `siteId` and `uniqueref` as I believe this is a popular way to try and distribute data evenly. In all cases we can include the `siteId` in a search and in 82% of cases we can include `uniqueref` so we could then silently create and add the synthetic key. The remaining 18% or so of queries are likely to be more throughput hungry but this is probably still better than the very significant SQL Server resource costs these searches generate. Trouble is, as a very visual learner I am having trouble visualising how this will distribute the data! The combination of `siteId` and `uniqueref` is likely to not be so much as a spread of values as unique values.

Document size is variable but likely to be in the region of 1.5KB to maybe 2.5KB on average. I don't yet know the maximum number of documents per site but this will grow anyway and I don't think we're at the 4 million mark for any one site just yet, which would be somewhere around the 10GB limit for partitions. I'm not sure how much this does or should influence my key choice.

My experience with Cosmos is limited so I'm unsure how to proceed. Should I use a unique value, a value which has an uneven distribution of data or a value which may not be unique but is likely to have a huge spread of values?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about unbalanced partitions with differing amounts of data in each. I would worry about making sure you don't need to query across lots of partitions, as that is an expensive and potentially unfeasible operation depending on the number of partitions involved. Each physical CosmosDB partition has a 10GB limit; just make sure you don't end up with dozens and dozens of GB of data in a single partition when you choose your key.

Comment: @RobReagan I probably can't avoid cross partition queries in about 20% of cases or less, but I'm not as worried about those. I guess the only thing I can do is try and make an assessment of how many records each `siteid` has and then guesstimate storage based on a rough average document size. Using a synthetic key means every record would be in it's own logical partition, I think, which sounds inefficient, and the `uniqueref` would also lead to many thousands or tens of thousands of logical partitions. Does the number of logical partitions matter or affect performance in any way?

Comment: Of course, a high number of logical partitions increases your chances of cross partition queries, I should have remembered that, but apart from that is there any other penalty for a lot of logical partitions?

Comment: There's no other penalty.

Comment: Thanks. I think about 20% of my queries will probably have to be cross partition so I definitely want to stay away from having high numbers of logical partitions.